# How to pinch google map when it set in UIScrollView in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, uiscrollview

I set **Google Map** in view in **UIScrollView**. everything OK but i can not **pinch** my map. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Salaam Reza jaan.

In your case you can use something like this. Cheers.

Edit: this is a better way to do it. Behbakht shid, direh inja :P

```
- (void) scaleSelfWith:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
if ([gestureRecognizer numberOfTouches] >1) {

    //getting width and height between gestureCenter and one of my finger
    float x = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self].x - [gestureRecognizer locationOfTouch:1 inView:self].x;
    if (x<0) {
        x *= -1;
    }
    float y = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self].y - [gestureRecognizer locationOfTouch:1 inView:self].y;
    if (y<0) {
        y *= -1;
    }

    //set Border
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        xDis = self.bounds.size.width - x*2;
        yDis = self.bounds.size.height - y*2;
    }

    //double size cause x and y is just the way from the middle to my finger
    float width = x*2+xDis;
    if (width < 1) {
        width = 1;
    }
    float height = y*2+yDis;
    if (height < 1) {
        height = 1;
    }
    self.bounds = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x , self.bounds.origin.y , width, height);
    [gestureRecognizer setScale:1];
    [[self layer] setBorderWidth:2.f];
}
}
```

Comment: First i must add gesture on mapView?

Comment: gesture add to UIScrollView but can not add to self.mView(my map view).